# Changing all days in a pandas DF by one

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I imported a csv file into a pandas dataframe.
One of the columns is datetime format(YYY-MM-DD).
After reading it, I found out that all the dates are wrong, and all of them should be moved by 1 in order to match the correct cases. An example:

The dataframe I have is like this:

```
2020-12-07 has 903 new COVID-19 cases  
2020-12-06 has 1383 new COVID-19 cases  
2020-12-05 has 1648 new COVID-19 cases
```

Etc etc etc

I want to find a way to move the DD by one, so the data above looks like this:

```
2020-12-06 has 903 new COVID-19 cases  
2020-12-05 has 1383 new COVID-19 cases  
2020-12-05 has 1648 new COVID-19 cases
```

A link to the jupyter notebook, is this: [my_notebook_git](https://github.com/boonick/Covid-19-Greece-Prediction/blob/main/Covid.ipynb)

Comment: I think you have a mistake in the resulted DD you wish to have. Shouldn't it be 2020-12-05 as 1383.0 (because it shows 1648 in the original?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html).

assuming your df looks like this:

```
    Date_reported   New_cases
27879   2020-12-07  903
27878   2020-12-06  1383
27877   2020-12-05  1648
27876   2020-12-04  1882
27875   2020-12-03  2185
27874   2020-12-02  2199
27873   2020-12-01  1044
27872   2020-11-30  1193
27871   2020-11-29  1747
27870   2020-11-28  1981
```

you can apply:

```
df['New_cases'] = df['New_cases'].shift(1)
```

and get the desired result:

```
    Date_reported   New_cases
27879   2020-12-07  NaN
27878   2020-12-06  903.0
27877   2020-12-05  1383.0
27876   2020-12-04  1648.0
27875   2020-12-03  1882.0
27874   2020-12-02  2185.0
27873   2020-12-01  2199.0
27872   2020-11-30  1044.0
27871   2020-11-29  1193.0
27870   2020-11-28  1747.0
```

Comment: That wouldn't quite work for the example in the question, where the same date appears twice. Also, if there would be a gap in the dates, this would give a different result from what was asked.

Comment: @RobbytheBelgian Bonjour. If the date appears twice - you would have to group and sum. If there's a gap - you need a logic for this (either +1 in date or +1 in shift). For the records provided in his github it looks consistent.

Comment: I looked through the original data. The same date does occur multiple times, for different countries. If you want to deal with dates, you should use datetime, not string. See my answer for a different way of doing this.

Comment: @RobbytheBelgian yes, +1 for the dates.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should change the data type of the `Date_reported` column. (That's also why you're getting those warnings in those red boxes: these are treated as strings, and hence as categorical data).

`df.Date_reported = pd.to_datetime(df.Date_reported)`

Then, you can just add and subtract `timedelta` variables:

`df.Date_reported - np.timedelta64(1, 'D')`

```
0       2020-01-02
1       2020-01-03
2       2020-01-04
3       2020-01-05
4       2020-01-06
   ...    
79895   2020-12-02
79896   2020-12-03
79897   2020-12-04
79898   2020-12-05
79899   2020-12-06
Name: Date_reported, Length: 79900, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: recommend using bracket notion over date, also good practice to specify the date format imho. over than that good answer.

Comment: Thank you for the input, i swear they were already datetime format as i checked yesterday. I did as you instructed and changed it!